# KubernetesPodOperator Not Sending Arguments as expected

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, spark-submit

I have airflow running KubernetesPodOperator in order to do a Spark-submit call:

```
spark_image = f'{getenv("REGISTRY")}/myApp:{getenv("TAG")}'
j2g = KubernetesPodOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='myApp',
    name='myApp',
    namespace='data',
    image=spark_image,
    cmds=['/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit'],
    configmaps=["data"],
    arguments=[
        '--master k8s://https://10.96.0.1:443',
        '--deploy-mode cluster',
        '--name myApp',
        f'--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image={spark_image}',
        'local:///app/run.py'
    ],
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Unrecognized option: --master k8s://https://10.96.0.1:443
```

Which is weird, because when I bin/bash to a running pod and execute the spark-submit command, **it works**.

Any idea how to pass the arguments as expected?

Comment: is the `spark_image` contains its own entrypoint? `cmds` overrides the entrypoint, so you could check what happened on entrypoint of image

Comment: Did https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12700 solve you question?

Comment: @elad yes, I will update with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from GitHub ticket: Parameter should be sent like:

```
 '--master=k8s://https://10.96.0.1:443',
```